# destroy sessions before redirecting using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Could someone tell me what I'm missing. I'm just calling a page with session_start();
session_destroy();
This works most of the time but sometimes it will redirect me with the sessions still working, so I'm still logged in.

```
$("#logOut").click(function() {
    $.get("http://heber/QC/includes/pinInput/sessionDestroy.php",{},function(data) {
        window.location.href = "http://heber/QC/";   
    })
})
```

Comment: Share the code in page where you are destroying session variable

Comment: did you forget to stop the default action of following the link?

Comment: <?php
        session_start();
        session_destroy();
    ?>

Comment: (Kevin) Yes. That's probably it. How would I do that

Comment: @TimAllred http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/